# import bootstrap in typescript file not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, webpack, import

I am trying to import bootstrap into my typescript file so that I can use the bootstrap tooltip on SVG shapes that I am adding to a canvas based on a search result. Anyway, I an adding these SVGs in a typescript file and I need add the bootstrap tooltip which I am doing by calling `$('.tooltip').tooltip({title: "it works!"})`. However, in order to do this, I need to import both jQuery and bootstrap. I am able to import jQuery using -- `import * as $ from "JQuery";` -- however when i try to import bootstrap, using -- `import "bootstrap"` -- I get the following error message in the browser.

I am using node.js and have the latest bootstrap

[Browser Error Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G5zF.png)